# Dependencies installed via package managers

Tags: derivative-works, distribution, source-code, redistribution, npm

Is there any difference to provide for instance a npm package.json or to provide all the packages source code in the source code repository of the software project? What's the impact if the project has a free or open or propietary license?

I usually look at a `GitHub repository -> Insights -> Dependency Graph` and most of the times I see a reference to a file that lists dependencies but they are not provided in the source code repository. It has some relation with dynamic links or derivative works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

If you mention a dependency in `package.json` (or a similar file that gets used by a mackage manager),

- you only need to have the right to download & use the dependency, not the right to redistribute it. That latter right is usually not granted for proprietary software.
- you can automatically get the latest released version of the dependency

If you include the source code in your own repository

- you can only do that for dependencies that allow redistribution
- you can make changes to the dependency and use them before those changes are officially released
- you won't get unexpected upgrades of the dependency
- you need to arrange your repository in such a way that it is clear which code is yours and which comes from a dependency (that possibly uses a different license)

For the licensing options you have for your own code, it doesn't make a difference if the dependencies have their source code in the same repository or if they are downloaded via a package manager.