# I use the npm package, do I have to specify the license for each package?

Tags: copyright, license, npm

If I use a specific library and this library uses other packages..
In the event that I have a license and copyright notice, is it obligatory for this library or for all sub-packages?

Do I have to license and copyright notice to all packages or just this library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/dependencies-installed-via-package-managers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dependencies installed via package managers](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/dependencies-installed-via-package-managers)

Comment: I don't think,,

Comment: @user16733810, can you explain in what way you believe your question is different from that other question.